Z sorting on sprites?
I'm trying to capture individual 3D meshes into 2D sprites (to be clear I'm not trying to capture the entire viewport, just individual meshes)
For example I have a sphere and cube as such:

and I have the images generated for those corresponding 3D objects into 2D as such:

This works fine however as you can see in 2D the sphere sprite is drawn infront of the cube which is incorrect, so how do I create a custom "z sort" / "depth" property (similar to sorting of y sort enabled), such that I can simply set it's value to global_position.z of the corresponding 3D objects and it gets sorted automatically?
why not simply set the z index individually?
If 2 objects with children overlap they'll look intertwined also it would be a nightmare to navigate through all the z indexes manually.
Why not reorder the scene tree if you need to keep the same z index?
The 3D objects can move which would require reordering the 2D scene tree constantly which is not viable especially if there are large number of 3D objects (along with their children) and it would also be impossible to animate.
Edit: Here's a continuation of what I'm trying

You could do int(floor(global_position.z)). If the objects are closer together than 1 unit on the z axis, just multiply the global_position.z first as appropriate. This will have limited precision though as the z order is bounded to -4096,4096

@MaxAlexander neat suggestion but this won't work since the project is global_position.z sensitive so I can't clamp it to int

I don't mean setting the actual position, but rather using the clamped value as the z order.

@MaxAlexander ah I see but that would lead to some unmanageable z_index values e.g. 1.53->153 or 1.26->126 and yes it would also be limited to ±4096 or 40.96 meters (if precise till 2 decimals, even less if 3)
